# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: BROTLI

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet

I am trying to read simple parquet file using below code in eclipse but its giving error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: BROTLI

```
 val conf: SparkConf = new 
 SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("ParquetTest").set("parquet.compression", "SNAPPY")
 val sc: SparkContext = new SparkContext(conf)
 val sqlContext: SQLContext = new SQLContext(sc)
 val newDataDF = sqlContext.read.parquet("userdata1.parquet")
```

Comment: Hi, please provide the full error log. It would be helpful.

Comment: @RajaShekar Issue was with dependency version needed for reading parquete files in spark. after correcting version issue is resolved. Thanks !!

Comment: @user2672783 - I am facing same issue when I use this `libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hive" % "hive-jdbc" % "3.1.2"` dependency in build sbt file, could you please share the version which has solved this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Following the hint of dependency versioning problem, I found out that `parquet-avro` was included in my pom.xml. While `parquet-avro` is not required for the above mentioned example to run (it was used for a different purpose) it did break the code. The fix was to advance the `parquet-avro` to 1.11.0.

Answer (score 0):

Check this package: `org.apache.parquet.hadoop.metadata`, decompile the bytecode (IntelliJ does that for you). It should have

```
    UNCOMPRESSED((String)null, CompressionCodec.UNCOMPRESSED, ""),
    SNAPPY("org.apache.parquet.hadoop.codec.SnappyCodec", CompressionCodec.SNAPPY, ".snappy"),
    GZIP("org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec", CompressionCodec.GZIP, ".gz"),
    LZO("com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec", CompressionCodec.LZO, ".lzo"),
    BROTLI("org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BrotliCodec", CompressionCodec.BROTLI, ".br"),
    LZ4("org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.Lz4Codec", CompressionCodec.LZ4, ".lz4"),
    ZSTD("org.apache.parquet.hadoop.codec.ZstandardCodec", CompressionCodec.ZSTD, ".zstd");
```

If it's missing `BROTLI`, you can get this error. I fixed it by updating `parquet-format` package version. You need to see in your case what is consuming this dependency and update the version.